# Understanding Typescript definition files on Webstorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I started using Typescript with Webstorm today and I am getting real crazy understanding what's going on. Imagine a project using `tsd` loading definition types on `typings/`. For background, `angular` defines an `angular` module aliased to `ng` and then there is other `d.ts` files appending more modules into `angular` (and technically `ng`).

When I require for example the `router` I get:

[image: route is not resolved]

In fact, if you go to `angular-route.d.ts` (from DefinitelyTyped) you can see the same:

[image: not resolved in here too]

The `d.ts` files are technically correct because tsc compiles them giving it those definition files.

On the other hand, Webstorm allows you to load libraries (typescript stubs from DefinitelyTyped). If I go there and I download the `angular` ones (which are 100% the same as the one I have on `typings/`) I get:

[image: quite better]

Same error but at least I don't get the red wiggle in the solution explorer. Still, it doesn't give me any intellisense when writing `ng.route.<ctrl+space>`, it just turn blue when I finish writing it (in fact, I can cmd+click and go to the definition).

Who's failing here? The typescript plugin? It is weird that it fails using `typings/` and somehow work with Webstorm's libraries menu (using the same file).

Answer (score 1):

> Who's failing here? The typescript plugin?

Yes. You need to use the Webstorm beta channel to get support for TypeScript 1.4 union Types at the moment.

Comment: I am using Webstorm 10 EAP, isn't that enough?

Comment: may be [WEB-15797](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15797). Does the problem persists in WebStorm 10 RC?

Comment: I am not seeing that lena.